# (n)curses displays appear broken under iTerm2

Tags: linux, terminal, iterm2

When accessing any of the `*-tui` commands under CentOS/Red Hat, or any equivalents on other distributions, my display is completely broken and almost unusable.

This is what `authconfig-tui` running under CentOS6.4 looks like:
[image: iTerm2 output]

I'm using the UTF-8 character encoding on the terminal, and the terminal type is set to xterm-256color. As far as I know, these are the proper settings to use.

No other text mode GUI apps appear to be broken aside from these commands. For instance, `centerim`, `irssi`, `alpine` all work perfectly.

How do I fix this?

Comment: authconfig doesn't use ncurses - it uses slang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently a bug in iTerm2. As of the 2.9.2016xx, builds, `authconfig` does not display in this broken fashion anymore.